# Appending PHP variable in javascript url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I have the following

```
$id=$this->uri->segment(3);
```

I want to pass the variable data through a javascript url and I did it the following way :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",                   
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>pharm_profile/prescriptions/<?php $id; ?>",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(prescription) {               
                    prescription_list=$('#prescription_list').empty();                        
                    $.each(prescription, function(i, prescription){                          
                       prescription_list.append('<div style="color: white;"><a style="color: white;" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>pharm_profile/dispense_details/'+prescription.id+'">'+prescription.medname+'</a></a>\n\
            </br></div>');                        
                       // prescription_list.append('<li span="font_color:white !important;"><a href="<?php //echo base_url(); ?>transactions/details/'+prescription.medname+'">'+prescription.medname+'</a></li></a></br>');            
                    });
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    //alert(data);
                }
            });
        });


    });
</script>
```

When I run the script I only get url up to prescription leaving out the id. What is the best way to include the id?

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add `echo` before the variable

Change the url or four ajax

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>pharm_profile/prescriptions/<?php $id; ?>",
```

to this

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>pharm_profile/prescriptions/<?php echo $id; ?>",
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo` to set the `value` `$id`,

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>pharm_profile/prescriptions/<?php echo $id; ?>",
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line, you are missing `echo`:

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>pharm_profile/prescriptions/<?php echo $id; ?>",
```